# Openlayers - Mapbox Layer Tutorial Problem

Tags: openlayers

Just trying to get a basic open-layers example to work locally:

https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/mapbox-layer.html

But I'm getting the following error:

```
VM340:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getObject (JSONFeature.js:197)
    at GeoJSON.JSONFeature.readFeatures (JSONFeature.js:53)
    at VectorSource.<anonymous> (featureloader.js:86)
```

Seems like I get the error regardless of whether or not countries.geojson is present.

Comment: Does it work using `https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson`  If it does you probably need to define `.geojson` in your localhost mime types

Comment: Yes the url you provided does work, but from what I can see localhost mime types are only relevant if you're using a web server?

If I avoid Parcel I can get it running with a local source. Thanks for your help. I will score this one as a victory to the authors of obfuscated tutorials.

Comment: Can you open `http://localhost/......./countries.geojson` (fill in the full path) in your browser?  IIS has a habit of returning 404 for unknown extensions.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I'm not using IIS, didn't realize I had to just to run the basic examples. Referencing http://localhost/countries.geojson didn't work either.

But by including the ol.js library in the HTML seems to let me access the file locally, which is all I wanted to do for now.